# Bar Chart in processing, I can't get the size right

Tags: java, charts, processing

I am supposed to draw a 2D bar chart using the elements from an array .
I have to choose the bar width in function of the total number of values and the total window width; and the bar height in function of its particular value and the maximum value of all the elements, taking into account that the height of the bar of the element of maximum value is going to be the height of the window.
This is my code so far, and I am not getting the result that I want.

```
float[] values = {25.0, 45.0, 5.0, 15.0, 10.0};

void setup() {
size(400,400);
}
void draw() {
background(0);

 // draw axes (relative to screen edges)
  stroke(255,0,0);
  strokeWeight(5);
  line(0,height,width,height);
  line(0,0,0,height);

    barChart(values);
}

void barChart(float[] data){
  for (int x=0; x<400; x+=80) {    
    for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++){

      fill(20,128,55);
    rect(x,350,80,(data[i]/100)*400);  //x,y,width,height
      }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why divide by 100 and then multiply by 400? You could just multiply it by 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written that the bar width should be a "function of the total number of values and the total window width" but right now it is a constant (80).

You also write that the bar height should be a "function of its particular value and the maximum value of all the elements, taking into account that the height of the bar of the element of maximum value is going to be the height of the window" but right now it only depends on data value.

So of course that code *cannot* do what you expect it to do, you need to change those constants to be expressions based on those variables. Please do this and if you still get unexpected results, write what exactly you did, what output you expect and how the result differs.